# Python- Connecting Lines with plot_date in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to graph out some data in which takes time over a time, therefore I have to use plot_date in order to plot my lines. But for some reason Plot_Date and Plot have completely different formatting as far as connecting lines.

Here is what It looks like when using `plot(x,y)`
[image: Pic1]

Using `plot(x,y,'bo')` or `plot_date(x,y,'bo')`
[image: Pic2]

`Plot_date(x,y)` looks like that ^^ too.

and using `plot_date(x,y,'bo-')`
[image: Pic3]

How do I make it so that the result of `plot_date` looks like the first picture? I have looked all over the Matplotlib website and couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Upon further investigation I found that in order to display a solid line without dots, I needed to use the line style 'b-', making the code `plot_date(x,y,'b-')`.

Comment: actually to make it more readable it would be better to use `plot_date(x, y, linestyle='solid', marker='None')`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the markers connected with the lines, you can also use

```
plt.plot_date(y,x,linestyle='solid')
```

So the complete code for the beginners would be:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot_date(y,x,linestyle='solid')
plt.show()
```

Do not forget you need to have matplotlib installed first. For that you need to open command line and write:

```
pip install matplotlib
```